# how do i change the language prefix to the user stored prefered language

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-middleware

I am working on a multilanguage Django project and i am using i18n for that, what i want to do is store the user-preferred language, I have already done that and added a language field in the User model, so my approach to solve this problem was creating a middleware to change to the user preferred language:

```
from Django.utils import translation

class LanguageMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    
    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.language:
           translation.activate(request.user.language)
        else: 
            translation.activate(translation.get_language())
        
        
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

and I set the user language to 'ar', but if I try to enter with the URL

```
 127.0.0.1:8000/en
```

it doesn't work as expected and gives me this

```
1.ar/
The current path, en/, didn’t match any of these.
```

but what I wanted is to redirect it to this `127.0.0.1:8000/ar` either from this `127.0.0.1:8000` or this `127.0.0.1:8000/en` and of course, that will be based on the preferred language, and if the user is not authenticated it will be just based on the language data in the request, how can I do that please?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the language in `request.path_info` and (optionally) redirect:

```py
import re

from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils import translation


class LanguageMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.language:
            language = request.user.language
        else:
            language = translation.get_language()

        if not request.path_info.startswith(f'/{language}'):
            language_from_path = translation.get_language_from_path(request.path_info)
            if language_from_path:
                return redirect(re.sub(f'^/{language_from_path}', f'/{language}', request.path_info))
            return redirect(f'/{language}{request.path_info}')

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Comment: sorry for the late answer i'll try this  @aaron

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I see,you don't have that pattern to `urls.py` file, so you need to add the internalisation like in the example inside the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns

Then all the page, with different prefix language, but the same part after, are "redirect" to the same view.

Comment: i actually have it ```urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path(_('admin/'), admin.site.urls),

    path('',index, name='home'),
    path('rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    #path('lvastore/',)
    
)``` @luca-rigutti

Comment: it was working normally, but as in my question i wanted to change the prefix to the preferred language, and because i used a custom middleware it started giving me that error